# ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED triggered when phone start

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that play a sound when the phone charger is disconnected. Evrything works well but Android triggers the `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` when the phone boot, same when the charger is connected with `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`.

I understand why the OS would make such a thing but is it possible to know that this is due to reboot state, so my sound won't be played?

This happens on Nexus 4, haven't tested other devices.

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) {

    } else if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED) {
              //Don't want to get there if the phone is rebooting!
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured a solution to my problem, this could be a general and easy way to make sure device is not booting when charger intent is called.

Just catch the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` (don't forget manifest permission and intent) and set the timestant in a shared preference.

```
if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .edit();
        editor.putLong("uptime", System.currentTimeMillis());
        editor.commit();
        return;
    }
```

Then to be sure we're not in a boot sequence surround your code with a simple condition comparing to the system uptime:

```
    if (preferences.getLong("uptime", System.currentTimeMillis()) > System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.uptimeMillis()) {
               //Your code to be executed there!
    }
```

Hope this will help anyone!